# can't login with facebook from android app. gets this error: one or more of the given url is not allowed by the app's settings

Tags: android, facebook, mobile, oauth, nativescript

i trying to add a "login with facebook" button to my android app. i installed nativescript-facebook, but when the browser is open and i insert my email and password i get this error. i did some research and apperantly this occurs because i have to add my domain to "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs" on the facebook for developrs platform. the problem is i am not building a website but a mobile app which opens the facebook login screen on the browser, so i don't have a domain or uri. i have no clue what i am missing... i went through the settings in facebook for developers and turned to 'yes' everything i could think about. what am i missing?

Comment: have you set native or desktop app on ?

Comment: i had set native or desktop app on, the problem remains

Comment: Keep all uri's/url link fields empty.

Comment: all of the uri's fields are empty